# how to display version number on winform

Tags: winforms, version

i want to show the assembly version number on the form and i am stuck. the code will compile without errors and yet does not run. when i remove the lines below then the code will compile and run. i know that i am missing something here and i cannot see what it is. can someone point me in the right direction?

```
string Version = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        string version = "Version: " + Version;

        Form1.ActiveForm.Text = Version;
```

Comment: Add namespace using System.Reflection; and give it a try or change code to string Version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
            string version = "Version: " + Version;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use this method to get the version number.
versionInfo contains much more info than just the productversion so I am sure you can get from it what you need.

```
private string GetAppVersion()
{
   var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Application.ExecutablePath);
   return versionInfo.ProductVersion;
}
```

Comment: it's better to add some explain instead off only code

Comment: @Asieh It seemed self-explaning to me, but I followed your suggestion and added some info about the code.